# Trying to derive IPv4 address from given IPv4-mapped IPv6 address

Tags: java, ip-address, ipv6, ipv4

My problem statement says that I can receive either an IPv4 address or a v4-mapped v6 address as an InetSocketAddress instance. If it is a v4-mapped v6 address I've to derive the v4 address and use that.

I was reading the javadoc of InetAddresses and this is what it says:

```
 `Technically one can create a 128bit IPv6 address with the wire format of a
  "mapped" address, as shown above, and transmit it in an IPv6 packet header. 
  However, Java's InetAddress creation methods appear to adhere doggedly to the 
  original intent of the "mapped" address: all "mapped" addresses return 
  Inet4Address objects.`
```

I can determine if the received address is a v4-mapped v6 address using one the methods from this library like this:

```
  // Input is InetSocketAddress socketAddress

  if (InetAddresses.isMappedIPv4Address(socketAddress.getAddress().getHostAddress())) {
        System.out.println("This is a v4 mapped v6 address");
  }
```

As per the documentation none of the libraries (InetSocketAddress, InetAddress or InetAddresses) provides a method for deriving an IPv4 address from such a mapped input. So does it mean that type-casting the InetAddress received from InetSocketAddress to Inet4Address will be sufficient?

```
 Inet4Address inetAddress = (Inet4Address) socketAddress.getAddress();
```

If so, do I even need to use InetAddresses.isMappedIPv4Address? How can I determine if the casting failed or the given address is neither a valid IPv4 address nor a v4-mapped v6 address so I can throw an appropriate exception?

Answer (score 0):

[The IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) supports both IPv4 and IPv6 in a polymorphic manner.  It can accomplish what you are describing here.

Firstly, using that library, with your InetSocketAddress you can get an IPAddress:

```
InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = ...;
IPAddress addr = new IPAddressGenerator().from(inetSocketAddress.getAddress());
```

From there, you can check for IPv4 or IPv6:

```
boolean isIpv4 = addr.isIpv4();
boolean isIpv6 = addr.isIpv6();
```

Then if ipv6 or ipv6, you can use the associated subclass.  If Ipv6, from there you can check if the address is IPv4 mapped, IPv4 compatible, and so on.  If so, you can get the derived IPv4 address.  Afterwards, you can convert back to the java.net type instance.

```
if(isIpv4) {
    IPv4Address ipv4Address = addr.toIPv4();
    Inet4Address addr = ipv4Address.toInetAddress();
    ...
} else if(isIpv6) {
    IPv6Address ipv6Address = addr.toIPv6();
    if(ipv6Address.isIPv4Compatible() || ipv6Address.isIPv4Mapped()) {
        IPv4Address derivedIpv4Address = ipv6Address. getEmbeddedIPv4Address();
        Inet4Address addr = ipv4Address.toInetAddress();
        ...
    }
}
```

The javadoc is available at the link.